# Port Forward in Azure - Multiple VMs

Tags: azure, portforwarding, endpoints

I m tryng to setup  a game server on Azure.

I created 2 Vm with Windows 2008 and 1 With Linux.

In VM 1 - The game use 2 ports 7777 + 9014
In VM 2 - The game use 1 port  2106
In VM 3 - The web server will use Ports 80 + 21 + 8080

In Azure Manage portal, I create all machines in same network, all have the same external IP, but differents internal IPs.

How can I setup Azure to forward the ports to right machines? (Like we do with our router in home) ... I see something about end points but I m not sure about that.

Thakyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. When you drill into a VM using the Azure Management Portal, you should be able to Add a new endpoint under the "Endpoints" section. You will want to create a standalone endpoint for each port you wish to expose. The name is up to you, the public and private port will most likely be the same in your case and you can leave the checkboxes (Load-balanced set and direct server return) unchecked.

You mention they all have the same external IP, which is not an issue as long as all the ports are unique to each machine. In other words, you cannot have port 80 forwarded to both VM2 and VM3.

Finally, don't forget to open the corresponding private ports on the individual Virtual Machine's firewall as well.

Answer (score 0):

If they have the same external IP, you might want to consider putting VMs on separate cloud services, or have separate reserved VIP for each and all will still be on the same Vnet. This is a possible solution.